# Rounding in Sturges' formula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

English Wiki [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Sturges'_formula) that Sturges' formula is $$k = \lceil log_2(n) + 1 \rceil$$ whereas, for example, Russian Wiki [postulates](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) it as $$k = \lfloor log_2(n) + 1 \rfloor.$$ Other sources mention rounding to the nearest integer, and the [original paper](http://www2.esalq.usp.br/departamentos/lce/arquivos/aulas/2013/LCE0216/Sturges1926.pdf) does not compute $k$ at all, instead calculating class interval, later rounded to *convenient* multiplies of 2 and 5, which I guess was compensating for the lack of computers at that time.

So what is the difference between rounding logarithm down and up?

Comment: If you have a particular distribution in mind, generate its random deviates, and see if you can construct an improved rule based on examining repeated simulation runs.

Comment: Since all such formulas are rules of thumb to establish an initial number of bins *as a point of departure for creating a better histogram,* why would the rounding matter??

Comment: @whuber consider a chi squared test given some data from supposedly normal distribution. First we need to group data into k bins, and changing k might change value of statistic.

Comment: That's a good point.  In response, let me observe (1) if you do the grouping based on what you see in the data, the chi-squared test may be invalid; (2) if the decision is sensitive to the grouping, the results are going to be suspect unless every part of the data collection and analysis is conducted with utmost rigor.  See the discussion of the chi-squared test in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919.

Answer (score 1):

**Several frequently used rules.** Sturges' Rule is only one of [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width) the histogram binning rules in common use. Two other rules in common use include 'Freedman-Diaconis' and 'square root'. The choice of the number of bins
depends on the type of data to be illustrated, the purpose of the histogram, and the audience who will interpret it.
No rule is adequate for all situations.

The quest for 'convenient' bin boundaries did not disappear with the computer age. All software I have used seeks 'round number', equally-spaced boundaries.

**Histogram binning in practice.** For example, using basic graphics in R, `hist`, allows one to 'suggest' a number of bins, overriding the default formula, but R still choses boundaries authors of the procedure suppose are convenient. As explained in the [documentation for 'hist'](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/hist), parameter `br` also accepts codes for various methods.

One can also supply a 'mandatory' list of bin boundaries, but if bins are not of equal width, a density histogram is used so that the vertical axis makes sense. (Absent a compelling reason, I think it is a bad idea to specify unequal bin widths.)

**Several histograms for the same dataset.** We use a sample of size $n=10\,000$ from $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate} = 1/100).$ Here are a few examples of histograms in R--out of very many that might have been given:

In `hist` the default method of determining the number of bins is
Sturgis' rule which suggests about 14 bins. R uses a few more to make
'nice' boundaries. (I think some of your concerns about details of
using Strugis' rule become moot in practical applications.)

```
log2(10000)
[1] 13.28771

set.seed(606)
x = rexp(10000, .01)
hist(x)
```

[image]

By contrast, the Freedman-Diaconis rule suggests between 85 and 90 bins.
As I understand it, one purpose of this rule is to give a good
view of the density of the population from which the sample was
sampled, so the density function of $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=0.01)$
is superimposed on this histogram.

```
h = 2*IQR(x)/length(x)^(1/3)  # width of bars
k = diff(range(x))/h;  k      # number of bars
[1] 88.65872

hist(x, prob=T, br="FD")
  curve(dexp(x, .01), add=T, col="blue", n=10001)
```

[image]

If I want to make room for frequency labels, then I need fewer, wider bars.

```
hist(x, br=8, ylim=c(0,7000), label=T)
```

[image]

If I want roughly the same number of observations in each interval,
I need unequal bin widths for these data. Then the vertical
scale must be 'Density', and the density of my last interval 
would need to be expressed to five places. A clear purpose and
careful planning are necessary to get a useful result for a histogram
with unequal bin widths.

```
cutpt = c(0,100,200,400,1000)
hist(x, br=cutpt, ylim=c(0,.007), label=T)

mean(x > 400)/(1000-400)
[1] 3.033333e-05   # That is, 0.00003
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that data is drawn from approximately normal distribution, so Sturges' rule seems a reasonable choice, but your comparison of binning in one particular PL doesn't answer question at all. I'm interested in semantics behind choosing $n$ and $n+1$ for specific formulae

Comment: OK then, English and Russian Wikipedia do give slightly different answers. One uses the 'ceiling' (round up) function and one uses the 'floor' (round down) function. [This will certainly not be the only disagreement between two versions of a Wikipedia article.] But it **absolutely doesn't matter** because, in practice, Sturgis' and other rules are only approximate suggestions how many bins to use.  I attempted to illustrate this in my Answer. I'm sorry you feel it "doesn't answer your question at all!" [We try to frame answers to questions so they are of general interest.]